# Displaying Javascript variables in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have specified the question below after the code snippets.

app.js

```
app.route('/conn').post(function (req,res,next) {

        var sys =require('util');
        var myPythonScript ="script1.py";
        var path =resolve("C:\\Python27\\python.exe");
        var pythonExecutable = path;

        var uint8arrayToString = function(data){
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
        };

        const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        const scriptExecution = spawn(pythonExecutable, [myPythonScript]);

    // Handle normal output
    var chunk =' ';
    scriptExecution.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        chunk +=data;
    });
    scriptExecution.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(chunk);
    });

    // Handle error output
    scriptExecution.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        // As said before, convert the Uint8Array to a readable string.
        console.log(uint8arrayToString(data));
    });

    scriptExecution.on('exit', (code) => {
        //console.log("Process quit with code : " + code);

    });
    res.write('<h2>chunk</h2>');
    // End data write
    //scriptExecution.stdin.end();
    });
```

upload.html

```
<html>
<form action ="/file" method ="post">

    MAC Address:<br>
  <input type="text" name="macadd" id="macadd"><br>

  Percentage:<br>
  <input type="text" name="percent" id="percent"><br>


<input type="submit"  value='Submit' id="upload">
<br>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/home'" value='Home'><br>
<form action ="/conn" method= "post">
<input type="submit" value='Show Users'><br>
</form>

</html>
```

script1.py

```
import sys,time

def main():
    t=0
    while t!=5:
        t =t+1
        print t


# Start process
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The value of t is getting stored in the 'chunk' variable and through console.log() I am able to see the value of t on the console. I want to display these values on the upload.html page. How do I do this? I tried using res.render and res.write function but nothing got displayed. Any way to do this?

Comment: Use promises. Something like https://gist.github.com/Stuk/6226938 for spawning the child process and call `res.write()` in `then()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to display a variable in HTML from JS there is a simple(ish) way to do that. First you can create the element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Next, edit the created element. In the step before just give it an id (shown on the website above and below). https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp

Hope that works, 
Ben A.K.A BlackSky

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to display the values.

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
res.write('<h2>Connected Users are:</h2>' + chunk);
res.end();
```